# I see curly braces, parenthesis, and semicolons next to each other, why?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

Alright, so I have been looking into using the Smack library for XMPP, and I was looking at the documentation when I noticed something strange:

```
// Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection"._
ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("jsmith@jivesoftware.com", new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
});
```

The part that bothers me is the last line, when the

> });

Appears. I have never seen this before, and was wondering what it was, and when it would be used.

Comment: It is an anonymous inner class.  Look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Typically when you see `});` at the end of a block of code that means you are creating an anonymous class or object. You do this because you are going to reference the object only once, so there is no point into storing it in some variable since you will not use it again. If you are going to create an object that you are going to reference more than once, then store it in a variable.